# Optimization of a blackbox function

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, machine-learning

Let's say that we have an objective function $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$ which has the parameters $\mathbf x=[x_1\ldots x_n]$ and $\mathbf y=[y_1\ldots y_n]$. Here, $\mathbf y$ is a blackbox variable which is calculated from a simulation of a network $\mathcal N$ by taking  $\mathbf x$ as input.

$f$ is an objective function to be minimized for a given problem. Let's say:

$$
f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i+\beta_ix_iy_i
$$

where $\mathbf y= \mathcal N(\mathbf x)$ is a blackbox function whose analytical form is unknown which takes $\mathbf x$ as input

$\mathcal N$ refers to a network being simulated.

$\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are constants, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The problem has the following constraints:

$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i=C\\
x_i^\min \leq x_i \leq x_i^\max\\
0 \leq y_i \leq y_i^\max\\
0 \leq x_iy_i \leq (x_iy_i)^\max
$$
$C,x_i^\min, x_i^\max,y_i^\max,(x_iy_i)^\max$ being some fixed constants, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

A two-variable ($n=2$) example is as follows:

**Objective:**

$$
\min 2x_1+4x_1y_1+3x_2+5x_2y_2
$$

where

$$
[y_1,y_2]=\mathcal N([x_1,x_2])
$$

and $\alpha_1=2,\alpha_2=3,\beta_1=4,\beta_2=5$ according to the previous definitions.

**Constraints:**

$$
x_1+x_2 = 10\\
0\leq x_1\leq 10\\
5\leq x_2 \leq 10\\
0\leq y_1\leq 5\\
0\leq y_2\leq 10\\
0\leq x_1y_1\leq 50\\
0\leq x_2y_2\leq 50\\
$$

I have gone through some of the stochastic algorithms such as *simulated annealing*, *hill climbing*,  *evolutionary algorithms* like genetic algorithms, and so on. And I'm also aware that my problem containing a blackbox function within itself and subjected to a number of constraints has a high chance of falling into the ugly world of "No Free Lunch Theorem".

Are there any appropriate algorithms or suggestions that can solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the really great review and comparison of 22 derivative-free algorithms [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y)] (*written by two well-known and respected optimizers*). Here, the authors use the terms "*derivative-free*" and "*black box optimization*" synonymously (emphasis is mine):

> In addition, what we refer to as **derivative-free optimization is often also referred to as optimization over black boxes**. The literature on these terms is often inconsistent and confusing.

### Reference

1: [Rios, L. M., & Sahinidis, N. V. (2013). Derivative-free optimization: a review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations. Journal of Global Optimization, 56(3), 1247-1293.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y)

Answer (score 0):

[NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a nonlinear optimization library that can handle these kinds of problems. Most libraries cannot handle all of those constraints, but NLopt has some algorithms that can. From [the algorithms page](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/),

> Of these algorithms, only ISRES and ORIG_DIRECT support nonlinear inequality constraints, and only ISRES supports nonlinear equality constraints.

ISRES can be a little computationally intensive but it's the only global optimization algorithm I know of that allows nonlinear equality constraints.

The NLopt library has really nice bindings to Julia at [NLopt.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) if you'd like to use it in a higher level language.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to my method: https://github.com/avaneev/biteopt

I've tested it on a lot of functions, including those with non-linear constraints (but constraint programming requires a special approach which is demonstrated in examples).

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. To improve your answer you might explain the method and why this approach is appealing.